# How to parse command line arguments with flags and without

Tags: python, argparse

I typically use optparse/argparse to grab command line arguments but they always have a flag associated with them. (I have to write some stuff to work on python pre 2.6 and also post 2.6)

```
./myscript -d -v -f something
```

However, I now need to do something like this:

```
./myscript -d -v -f something -g something action
```

Where action is supplied without a -flag in front. (Sorry can't use a flag here, silly group I'm interfacing with don't wanna change their code)

I'd like to still use optparse/argparse but also grab the action argument. There is a variable number of -flag arguments that can be provided and only 1 bare action argument.

Comment: Would subparsers help?

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work in this case. I saw some code long time ago that was doing something just like this but can't for the life of me remember where or what they did exactly.

Comment: So you just want one argument that doesn't have a flag in front?

Comment: Yea, there will be an unknown number of "flagged" arguments in an unknown order, and a single "unflagged" argument. I can't even guarantee the unflagged argument can come last but if I have no way around it, I can probably force that requirement.

Comment: That's just the thing that `argparse` tries to do best.  You can even have several unflagged ones (their relative order does matter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a positional argument, just don't put a hyphen in front of the name, i.e.

```
parser.add_argument('action')
```

Comment: Well it won't actually say "action" it will be any number of possible strings, is that still doable?

Comment: Yes. Just access the `action` variable as any other flag variable, and it will contain whatever string is there.

Comment: Thx, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Yea that works great, it doesn't even matter the positioning of it!